# Kubuntu 12.04 wireless drivers

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kubuntu

I have been trying to get wireless drivers for a long time now. I updated everything in update manager and additional drivers. I can't find out how to get wireless networks. I don't want to use Ethernet. Thanks

Comment: Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and [edit] your question to include the necessary information. Thank you!

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title. Accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

1. Go to network settings.
2. Tap on "Wireless" tab
3. Add > wireless
4. Tap "Scan" next to SSID.
5. Tap on "Wireless security" tab
6. Select the security type you use
7. Type in password.
8. Tap OK.